# In how many ways can you make this stick?

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification

Assume that we have 10 marshmallows, 80 bananas, and 50 peaches.
Your task is to first put 3 marshmallows on a stick, then 2 bananas,
and finally 4 peaches. In how many ways can you make this stick?

Is this the correct solution to this particular problem? $\frac{9!}{4! 3!  2!}$

Comment: Yes, that's correct. $\binom{9}{3}\binom{6}{2}\binom{4}{4}$ assuming your marshmallows, bananas and peaches are undistinguishable.

Answer (score 1):

I would claim that if marshmallows etc. are indistinugishable, there is $1$ way because you are given a specific order the things must be in.  If they are distinguishable, there are $10 \cdot 9 \cdot 8\cdot 80\cdot 79 \cdot 50 \cdot 49 \cdot 48 \cdot 47$ ways.